# Adding a period after the numbering of the headings

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I already have a document with numbered headings. However there's no period after each heading numbering. How do I add that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click the arrow next to Numbering option

[image]

2. Select `Define new number format`

[image]

3. Enter a dot next to the number, then click OK.

Comment: Do I have to do it for all headings?

Comment: Also this breaks the hierarchy

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a picture or example of your hierarchy? How it is broken?

Comment: It's very simple: Heading 1 should look like this `1.` heading 2 should look like this: `1.1.`

Comment: What do you get when you add Heading 2 that breaks your hierachy?

Comment: The number of the superior heading doesn't show up in the numbering anymore. I don't remember how I got it to work originally. All I remember is that it was also a massive pain.

Comment: Click on `Multilevel list` option (it is next to the `Numbering` option on the right). Select 1, 1.1, 1.1.1. Then click on` Numbering` option followed by `Change level list` and select 1.1 (for heading 2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87335/discussion-between-philippe-and-reddy-lutonadio).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Multilevel List Editor to create *all* numbered lists and headings. Using the Numbered List dialog usually ends up in grief, as does the use of the Paragraph editor.

I refer you to Shauna Kelly's website, [Making the Most of Word for your Business](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/outlinenumbering.html).

Look at Step #1 and go from there to the instructions to create numbered headings that won't blow up in your face ;-)

Using multilevel lists allows you to set the numbering type (1, A, I, etc.), add other text to the headings (e.g., Chapter, Section, etc.), set the fonts, set the indents, and add tabs.

(Trust me, when Word's barfs on your headings, it is not quick fix)

[Shauna died many years ago](https://shaunakelly.com/about/about.html), but her site is kept alive to benefit Word users.